# Elasticsearch date range check for nested array of date ranges

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nest

all devs, this is my first question here please ignore my mistakes. I am working on a project where I have a list of booking. This list has start and end dates, and for elasticsearch I already have declared and indexed them as nested

```
"Bookings":[{
    "StartDate":"2017-01-10T10:00:00+11:00",
    "EndDate":"2017-01-15T21:30:00+11:00"
  },{
    "StartDate":"2017-01-20T10:00:00+11:00",
    "EndDate":"2017-01-25T00:00:00+11:00"
  }]
```

but when I try to check availability the results are not as expected, here is json of elasticsearch which I am running

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 12,
  "_source": [
    "Id",
    "Bookings"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Bookings",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {"range": {"Bookings.StartDate": {"gte": "2018-01-06T00:00:00+11:00"}}},
                        {"range": {"Bookings.EndDate": {"lte": "2018-01-09T00:00:00+11:00"}}}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When search dates are 06-01-2018 (startDate) and 09-01-2018(endDate), results are fine but when I change dates to 06-01-2018 (startDate) and 11-01-2018(endDate) results went wrong but as per nested logic it should give me a booking which is from 10-01-2018 to 15-01-2018 as endDate (11-01-2018) falls in the range. Can anyone please help me in fixing the logic to check the availability and no bookings are in the range of search start and end dates?

Comment: Looks like the casing of the field names is incorrect - `"Bookings.startDate"` in the document vs. `"Bookings.StartDate"` in the query. Same for the end date.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out but when i edited the code to paste here i forgot to change casing. In actual code both are same spellings

Comment: @Ravian : I am facing the same problem, the date range is not working properly on my list of objects.
can you please share your mapping of field `Bookings`. It can help me to solve my problem, whether my mapping is correct or not.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? what info do you need? i am more than happy to assist you to make it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with adding an extra list of all dates inside the parent object i.e BookingDates which I update on every booking/cancellation to add and remove dates.  For elastic search, i am simply checking in the filter if the list dates fall in the search range.

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must_not": [
      {
        "range": {
          "BookingDates": {
            "gte": "2018-01-16T00:00:00+11:00",
            "lte": "2018-01-20T00:00:00+11:00"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if anyone has better approach please share, I am sharing my logic because I am failed to find the answer of this/similar question. May be this could help someone in similar situation.